# Save associations with Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a problem with CakePHP 3 and saving new entity and its associations with one operation.

In my opinion I do it like recommended in the documentation.

Here my controller:

```php
$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');       
$article = $articles->newEntity($this->request->data);  

if ($this->request->is('post')) {            

    $valid = $articles->validate($article, [
        'associated' => ['Topics']
    ]);

    if ( $valid ) {
        $articles->save($article, [
            'validate' => false,
            'associated' => ['Topics']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Thats my models:

```php
class ArticlesTable extends Table {   
    public function initialize(array $config) {        
        $this->primaryKey('article_id');
        $this->belongsTo ( 'Topics', [
            'targetForeignKey'  => 'topic_id'
        ]);
    }
}

class TopicsTable extends Table {  
    public function initialize(array $config) {        
        $this->primaryKey('topic_id');  
        $this->hasMany ( 'Articles', [
            'targetForeignKey'  => 'article_id'
        ]);    
}
```

And this is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_title` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

MY form looks like that:

```html
<input type="text" id="articles-heading" maxlength="45" required="required" name="Articles[heading]">
<input type="text" id="articles-topics-topic-title" list="topics" name="Articles[Topics][topic_title]">
```

I want to create a form which contains all the associations and save it with one request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Missing columns

There is no column named `heading` in your `articles` table.

### Invalid foreign key configuration

Your configuration looks wrong, `targetForeignKey` is for `BelongsToMany` associations, and `article_id` (the primary key of the other table) is *not* the foreign key in an `Topic hasMany Comment` association, it's `topic_id`, and it's not necessary to specify it when you're following the naming conventions.

So when specifiying the foreign keys at all, it should look something like this:

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table {   
    public function initialize(array $config) {        
        $this->primaryKey('article_id');
        $this->belongsTo ( 'Topics', [
            'foreignKey' => 'topic_id'
        ]);
    }
}

class TopicsTable extends Table {  
    public function initialize(array $config) {        
        $this->primaryKey('topic_id');  
        $this->hasMany ( 'Articles', [
            'foreignKey' => 'topic_id'
        ]);   
    } 
}
```

You could avoid a lot of confusion if you'd stick to the convention and name your primary keys `id`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Table Objects > Basic Usage](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#basic-usage)**
- **[Cookbook > Models > Table Objects > HasMany Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#hasmany-associations)**

### Possibly missing accessibility configuration

Since you are trying to save non-default fields (that is `Topic` data instead of `Topic` primary key), you'll have to make the field accessible for mass assignment via `newEntity`. This is possible for example via the `Entitiy::$_accessible` property, which is permanent for every single instance of that entity until overriden at runtime

```
class Article extends Entity {
    protected $_accessible = [
        // ...
        'topic' => true
    ];
}
```

or by using the `accessibleFields` option for `Table::newEntity()`, which only applies to that one single instance.

```
$article = $articles->newEntity($this->request->data, [
    'accessibleFields' => [
        'topic' => true
    ]
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Entities > Mass Assignment](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment)**
- **[API > Cake\ORM\Table::newEntity()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_newEntity)**

### Field Naming Conventions

Finally your form data is incorrectly formatted, names should by default be lowercase and underscored in order to match the entities properties, and they should be singular (unless it's a `hasMany` or `belongsToMany` association), ie it should be `article` and `topic` instead of `Articles` and `Topics`, also it's actually not necessary to use `article` at all.

```
echo $this->Form->input('heading');
echo $this->Form->input('topic.topic_title');
```

```
<input type="text" name="heading">
<input type="text" name="topic[topic_title]">
```

See also **[Cookbook > Helpers > FormHelper > Field Naming Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions)**

Comment: I just forgot the column heading in the example above. I tried your solution and I have to say: Thank you so much! It works perfectly.